# My Visual Studio Code is not working properly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can't get the Python symbol in my Visual Studio Code and also I can't run my programs. If I run the programs it is not appearing neither on the terminal nor on the output I have downloaded the python extensions but also the same problem is occurring, and if type pr it should show the options such as print but that is also not appearing.

As I have seen many YouTube videos I think the problem is its not showing the Python symbol. I've also added the screenshot of my Visual Studio Code.

I am a 10th standard student, how can I find a solution?

[Screenshot of my Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab7UF.jpg)

Comment: Update your question with what Python version you've installed and what's the exact extension you've setup on VS Code

Answer (score 0):

On your bottom right, you chose the wrong language. Click on "Batch" then type in & choose "Python"